# An error occurred when the ASAP(Automated Slide Analysis Platform) software was running

Tags: qt, cmake

With the enthusiastic help of SO netizens, I configured all the environments required for ASAP (Automated Slide Analysis Platform)
The necessary libraries including Boost, Openslide, Qt, etc. have been successfully linked, but the following error occurred

```
====================[ Build | ASAP | Debug ]====================================
"D:\_Jason\Clion\CLion 2021.2.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\_Jason\C++_hospital\orignal\CLion1.9\ASAP-1.9\cmake-build-debug --target ASAP -- -j 9
[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target ASAP
[ 25%] Built target ASAP_autogen
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ASAP.exe
CMakeFiles\ASAP.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4ASAPC1EP7QWidget'
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QWidget4showEv'
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplication4execEv'
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4ASAPD1Ev'
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4ASAPD1Ev'
D:/_Jason/C++_hospital/orignal/CLion1.9/ASAP-1.9/ASAP/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\ASAP.dir\build.make:111: ASAP.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:163: CMakeFiles/ASAP.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:170: CMakeFiles/ASAP.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:168: ASAP] Error 2
```

It can be seen from "__imp__ZN12QApplicationD1Ev" that this is a Qt problem. The solution they gave in other forums is to add the statement `QT += gui widgets core` to the .pro file under this project.However, there is no .pro file in the ASAP source code, so I tried to use the qmake -project command to generate the .pro file. It still doesn't work after adding `QT += gui widgets core`

Comment: The required linkage is done at [ASAP/CMakeLists.txt:48](https://github.com/computationalpathologygroup/ASAP/blob/master/ASAP/CMakeLists.txt#L48) with `target_link_libraries(ASAP PRIVATE ASAPLib Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)`. Probably, your QT installation is incompatible with the compiler used when build ASAP. How have you installed QT on your machine?

Comment: BTW, you got a **linker** error, not the error when run the ASAP. This **conflicts** with your title ("An error occurred when the ASAP software was running"). Please, in the question post and in the title use correct description for your problem. You have already noted about that in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325560/clion-cant-use-boost-library-correctly).

Comment: Sorry for making the same mistake the second time. I have never used a forum like SO. I think this is indeed a link error, but I have also configured Qt and the source files in the project can be read normally. Qt header files, is this also due to linker errors?